# Upgrate elasticsearch2.4 to elasticsearch7.x

Tags: elasticsearch, migration

Can somebody please guide me that following questions while upgrading es2 to es7

1. Is it possible to directly upgrade to es2 to es7 ?
2. do we need to do mapping ?
3. how to handle **_parent** fields that are already exist in es2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Is it possible to directly upgrade to es2 to es7 ?**

No, it's not possible, ES provides the backward compatibility only till last major version, as mentioned in [ES upgrade docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html) and there are a lot of breaking changes, from es2 to es7.

**2. do we need to do mapping ?**

It's not clear what exactly you mean, but yes, as mentioned there are lot of breaking changes in mapping as well, like [removal of types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html), `string` data-type is changed to `text` to name a few, so it's better you define your new mapping according to latest syntax.

**3.how to handle _parent fields that are already exist in es2.?**

Not much familiar with this but you can read the docs and migration guide on it.

Comment: thanks for quick response. but can I do follow steps to achieve my goal

1) Create a new 6.x cluster and reindex from remote to import indices directly from the 2.x cluster. [ https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/reindex-upgrade.html ]
2) then do the same from 6 to 7

Comment: @WaqasAfzal you are on es2, first you have to do es2->es5, than es5->es6 and at last es6->es7, which is too many steps and in each steps you will have to encounter many issues and fixed before you finally reach to es7, instead of it much better and cleaner approach which I have seen is to prepare in your code base to upgrade to es7 directly.

Comment: can you please guide a little bit how can we do that in "code base" or any usefull link of doing that. Thanks